# Facebook SDK works on PHP 5.2, not on 5.3

Tags: json, facebook, curl, php-5.3, facebook-php-sdk

I'm having a terrible time of it trying to implement the Facebook PHP SDK on a new server. I'm running the following code:

```
require('facebook.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => "###",
    'secret' => "###",
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];

if ($like_status) {
    include('fan.php');
}
else {
    include('visitor.php');
}
```

This all works perfectly under my server running PHP 5.2.17, but breaks under PHP 5.3.3. Both servers have cURL and JSON functioning properly. As far as I can tell, no errors are being thrown, but `$facebook->getSignedRequest();` is returning as `null`.

I'm almost certain that there's something in my server configuration that's bollocksing the whole thing up, but for the life of me I can't figure out what. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Blocked ports maybe? Try checking your firewall.

Comment: The server is pretty locked down; any idea what ports I should look at?

Comment: I would try cURL requests on port 80, 443, 591, and 593 (HTTP/S and its alternates), as well as checking those ports on the firewall. That will give you an idea of what resources you as a user have access to, and what your PHP scripts can access.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the FB PHP SDK, `getSignedRequest` method and it used the [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) superglobal, the PHP manual says that in

> 5.3.0 - Introduced [request_order](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order). This directive affects the contents of
>   $_REQUEST.

Either the values of $_REQUEST are overwritten somehow. This might be something to look into.

Comment: Switching it around from `$facebook->getSignedRequest();` to `$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];` returns `Notice: Undefined index: signed_request`. Not exactly sure if this is closer or further from a solution. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: @Wyatt Did you try checking if `$_GET` and `$_POST` contains something that is not in `$_REQUEST`?